# JQuery - Adding content, indepent from wordpress theme

Tags: jquery

i want to write a simple function with the help of JQuery. I created this jfiddle:

```
<table class="my_table">
    <tr>
        <td class="correct"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="my_button" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="incorrect"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="my_button" />
        </td>
    </tr>
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xz3xc/1/

After the click, some content is added to the  above of the button. This is the case on my local machine. I run another theme on my wordpress and the code there looks like this:

```
<table class="my_table">
    <tr>
        <td class="correct"></td>
        <td>
            <div>
            <input type="button" class="my_button" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="correct"></td>
        <td>
            <div>
            <input type="button" class="my_button" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KuACZ/1/

There, of course the code is not working because one parent() is missing in the function. How can i write this function generic that it always takes the first td in the same tr where the button has been clicked, so that it is independent from the theme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code finds all the `td`'s with class `correct` within the same `tr`.

```
$('.my_button').click(function() {
   $(this).parentsUntil("tr").siblings("td.correct").html('Test'); 
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PMs4s/3/)